# How to loop through a multidimensional array with breakpoints?

Tags: jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array, each

I realize that 'breakpoint' may not be the right term.

I have

```
var sections = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    questions = [];
```

Each section has X number of questions, and the number of questions per section could be different. I need to be able to only show one section's worth of questions at any given time. So, `section[0]` might have three questions. I want to be able to view only those three questions, write answers, and move onto the next section. I have the HTML for this. I am just missing the part in the jQuery that is basically "ok, no more questions for this section, move to next section." How do I go about this? I am likely not using the correct terminology. What I have now is

```
$.each(sections, function(i, section) {
    $.each(questions, function(j, question) {
        // stuff to show questions
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each `section` in `sections` array is an array of `question` items, you can simply target the `value` property of `$.each()` you aliased as `section`:

```
var sections = [
        [{ questionId: 1 }, { questionId: 2 }, { questionId: 3 }], //questions for section 1
        [{ questionId: 1 }, { questionId: 2 }, { questionId: 3 }, { questionId: 4 }, { questionId: 5 }], //questions for section 2
        [{ questionId: 1 }, { questionId: 2 }] //questions for section 3
    ];

$.each(sections, function(i, section) {
    console.log("section " + i + ":");

    $.each(section, function(j, question) {
        console.log("\t" + question.questionId);
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5wdy25yy/2/) demonstrating some sample functionality

You'd want to structure the sections with having an array of questions object/items in each section. If you need to have an entirely different structure with a separate array for sections and separate array for question, this functionality would need to change as you'd need to associate a given question with a given section via an identifier.

Here is an example of one way to achieve that using `filter()`:

```
var sections = [
    { sectionId: 1 },
    { sectionId: 2 },
    { sectionId: 3 },
    { sectionId: 4 },
    { sectionId: 5 },
];

var questions = [
    { questionId: 1, sectionId: 1 },
    { questionId: 2, sectionId: 1 },
    { questionId: 3, sectionId: 2 },
    { questionId: 4, sectionId: 3 },
    { questionId: 5, sectionId: 1 },
    { questionId: 6, sectionId: 4 },
    { questionId: 7, sectionId: 1 },
    { questionId: 8, sectionId: 5 }
];

console.log("**********Example 2**********")
$.each(sections, function(index, section) {
    console.log("Section " + section.sectionId + ":");

    var relatedQuestions = questions.filter(function(question) {
        return question.sectionId === section.sectionId;
    });

    $.each(relatedQuestions, function(index, question) {
        console.log("\tQuestion " + question.questionId);
    });
});
```

Comment: I feel like I'm missing some kind of conditional statement in there. Like if ( /* last question for section */ ) { /*stop*/ }

Comment: For each inner loop, as soon as the question objects/items run out, it will automatically go to the next section and start on those question objects/items.

Comment: I've added an example jsfiddle demonstrating the functionality. You can see the output in the developer tools console. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, the questions array should be an inner array for sections. I think that's where I'm getting stuck.

Comment: I've added another example where in case you'd need association between separate arrays via something like number ids.